# Losing reference of window when changing window.location?

Tags: javascript, reference

I am basically losing the reference to the window after changing it's location.href, any help much appreciated.

```
var win = window.open(window.location,"foo","");
//win is referenced - all good
win.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
//url of window is successfully changed
//but I now no-longer have reference to this window
```

Comment: The other window, after the location update, holds a page fetched from a domain different from yours. Thus you won't be able to do anything with it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Once the location of a page changes, all execution of the current page ends.

Comment: But ... he's changing the location of a **different** window, the one opened with the "window.open" call.  The calling window will still be alive and well after that.  I think the OP means that the variable "win" no longer refers to that other window (or, perhaps, that it **appears** no longer to so refer).

Comment: You are correct, Pointy. Same-origin-policy makes it moot anyway.